# Finding Controls In A Data-Bound Template

Tags: asp.net

I'd like to find out if a certain type of control exists on a page. It's easy enough to iterate through the Controls collection recursively but I'd also like to check on first load whether the control exists in any of the templates  (ContentTemplate, EditItemTemplate, ItemTemplate, SelectedItemTemplate etc) contained in a control as well. Does anyone know if its possible, and if so how? There doesn't appear to be a Templates collection per se and it isn't obvious how to query an ITemplate for its contents.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I understand your question.  A template is used to render multiple copies of a data-bound control (e.g. a data-bound DropDownList in several rows in a GridView come from one template).  Trying to find a control in a template like that seems like an exercise in futility.

If you are looking for a control in a specific control that would be rendered by a template (i.e. a specific DropDownList from *one* of the rows in a GridView) then you could do something like GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("myDropDownList"), but you would still be doing this for each control you wanted to find.